# ServiceLoader doesn't load implementation

Tags: java, serviceloader

I really did a lot of research before asking this, it seems like I'm missing something. I try to implement a ServiceLoader and therefore made an example class:

[image: Project structure]

the code is simple:

*testInterface.java*

```
package com.test;

public interface testInterface {
    void test();
}
```

*testImpl.java*

```
package com.test;

public class testImpl implements testInterface {

    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

}
```

*Main.java*

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServiceLoader<testInterface> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(testInterface.class);

        serviceLoader.iterator().next().test();
    }

}
```

*com.test.testInterface*

```
com.test.testImpl
```

I keep getting a NoSuchElementException at the iterator part which means that the implementation was not loaded. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your META-INF/services/ into resources/ and add it to the Eclipse project as a source folder. It will be automatically included in the JAR file when you compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I knew it would be something this simple. I saw this project structure in other videos / posts and thought it was correct, seems like it was wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just had this problem; if anyone else is having it too, make sure that when the resources/ directory is linked, it's including that type of file.  Took me forever to figure out; thanks Eclipse!

Comment: If you're using modules, make sure to also add `provides` and `uses` statements in your `module-info.java` otherwise you run into the same `NoSuchElementException`!

If the above example was contained in a module, you'll need to add:

`provides com.test.testInterface with com.test.testImpl;`
`uses com.test.testInterface;`